# Auto close InfoWindow in googlemap

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I do not know how to do in order to automatically close a *InfoWindow* when another opens.

```
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, title, race, loc, org, web, link) {
  var infoWindowVisible = (function () {
          var currentlyVisible = false;
          return function (visible) {
              if (visible !== undefined) {
                  currentlyVisible = visible;
              }
              return currentlyVisible;
           };
       }());
       iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
           if (infoWindowVisible()) {
               iw.close();
               infoWindowVisible(false);
           } else {
               var html= "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:250px;'><h4>"+title+"</h4><p>Race</p><h4>"+race+"</h4><p>Location</p><h4>"+loc+"</h4><hr /><p>Organizzazione</p><h4>"+org+"</h4><a href='"+link+"'' >"+web+"<a></div>";
               iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:html});
               iw.open(map,marker);
               infoWindowVisible(true);
           }
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(iw, 'closeclick', function () {
        infoWindowVisible(false);
    });
}
```

I tried but I can not find my type cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one infowindow ever, only create one InfoWindow (in the global scope), reuse it and change its contents when a marker is clicked, close it if the user clicks on the map.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321808/close-infowindow-before-open-another)

```
 var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // single global infowindow
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
   iw.close();
 });
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, title, race, loc, org, web, link) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     iw.close();
     var html= "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:250px;'><h4>"+title+"</h4><p>Race</p><h4>"+race+"</h4><p>Location</p><h4>"+loc+"</h4><hr /><p>Organizzazione</p><h4>"+org+"</h4><a href='"+link+"'' >"+web+"<a></div>";
     iw.setContent(html);
     iw.open(map,marker);
   });
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13ro7yet/) - different code as you didn't provide a complete example, demonstrates the concept.