# Google Maps Infowindow weird expanding/transition upon second opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to display markers and I made info window for each of those markers; now everything runs perfectly until I click on close - every infowindow that was closed either by "X" or by infowindow.close(); next time when opened expands really slowly, here is the capture: 
[image]

It expands for like 20-30 seconds, pauses if window is not in focus.
This only happens if infowindow was already opened and then closed either via "X" or via .close();

[image: t]
These are the values, they go from zero to these values for like 20 secs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It can be prevented by:
`* {-webkit-transition: none !important;-moz-transition: none !important;-o-transition: none !important;-ms-transition: none !important;transition: none !important;}`

But then all transitions in the design, and in the map (moving from one marker to another) are disabled - I need a way to disable just infowindows values transition (what's weird even z-index transitions from 0 to end value).

Comment: Will need your code, but see if this is your issue: [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984258/change-google-maps-to-re-use-single-infowindow-rather-than-creating-multiple)